# Flutter:How I create a Hive DAO class in flutter/dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, hive

I need to group all operations of a Hivebd crud get, put, delete and update in one class but when I try this get a error because Hive.openBox() need an await but constructors not allowed async.How I would do that corectely?

My class below.

```
class HomeListRepository {
  var _homelistStore = await Hive.openBox<HomeList>("homelists");

  Future insert(String id, HomeList homelist) async {
    await _homelistStore.put(id,homelist.toMap());
  }

  Future update(HomeList homelist) async {
    await _homelistStore.put(homelist.id,homelist.toMap());
  }

  Future delete(HomeList homelist) async {
    await _homelistStore.delete(homelist.id);
  }

  Future<List<HomeList>> getAll() async {
    return _homelistStore.values;
  }

}
```

**Edit:**
I solved this and the final code is:

```
class HomeListRepository {
  Box _homelistStore;
  
  Future<void> insert(String id,HomeList homelist) async {
    _homelistStore = await Hive.openBox<HomeList>("homelists");
    _homelistStore.put(id,homelist);
  }

  Future<void> update(HomeList homelist) async {
    _homelistStore = await Hive.openBox<HomeList>("homelists");
    await _homelistStore.put(homelist.id,homelist);
  }

  Future<void> delete(HomeList homelist) async {
    _homelistStore = await Hive.openBox<HomeList>("homelists");
    await _homelistStore.delete(homelist.id);
  }

  Future<List<HomeList>> readAll() async {
    _homelistStore = await Hive.openBox<HomeList>("homelists");
    return _homelistStore.values.toList();
  }
}
```

finded on Hive github page:[GitHub](https://github.com/hivedb/hive/issues/93)